# What are the steps to combine Raspberry Pi 2 and NFC?

Tags: pi-2, nfc

My ultimate project is relatively simple: I would like to tap my iPhone onto my Raspberry Pi 2 in order to change a setting, such as turning the brightness all the way up, on my phone.

I'm brand new to working with the RP2, and I couldn't find any documentation that would help a beginner like me. How do I add NFC functionality to the RP2? Any helpful links/advice/steps would be super helpful!

Comment: Try the popular NFC chip MFRC522, which uses SPI (you can keep the UART on the RPi), found a [library using python](https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python) after a bit of search. You can get those NFC modules quite chip on ebay.

Answer (score 2):

Adafruit have a tutorial [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-nfc-rfid-on-raspberry-pi/overview) based on their own [NFC breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/364).

Looks like the outline steps are:

- Use `raspi-config` to disable UART.
- Download, configure and build [libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc).
- Plug in the Adafruit NFC breakout board.
- Do NFC things.

Comment: Also take a look to [this one](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/nfc-and-reader-ics/nfc-frontend-solutions/explore-nfc-exclusive-from-element14:PNEV512R?)